How do multimeters measure very high resistances, and how does (human) body capacitance affect it? I would like a technical answer
Technically speaking, how does a multimeter (Fluke 289 in my case), measure impedance (resistive only), and why does touching a metal case you are measuring with your hand change the reading "drastically"? See below for details on the part I'm measuring.
My educated guess it that the meter is outputting a constant current, measures the volts across the leads that it has to generate to produce the current. Using V=IR (actually R=V/I) it calculates the resistance of the item being measured. Touching the metal object adds your body capacitance, and the current starts charging your body capacitance at a rate given by the resistance of the pin to case and your skin resistance etc. My question is, why do I witness the ohms going downward in some instances? Not switching leads. Repeated touches with finger.
In some instances, the parts we measure are above the 500 MΩ threshold of this meter. The meter shows OL. But when I touch the case, the meter shows impedance (450 MΩ for instance). I suppose that either a) no current is flowing in the OL case (therefore the voltage is outputting it's highest value), or b) the voltage/current combination is outside the parameters that the designer set for accurate measurement. And touching the part causes enough current to flow to bring the parameters into the range that the meter can measure.
Some of you will say, just don't touch the case. I get it. But I want to confirm my technical understanding of this phenomenon. And sometimes I have to hold the case, and I want to know how much I'm skewing the measurement by just holding it, and if this is repeatable (I don't believe it is).
Details on the part I'm measuring: I'm trying to measure leakage for a product line with a Fluke 289. The case is metal, around 1 cm in diameter, and 3 mm thick. There is are a few 2 mm diameter holes drilled, spaced a several mm apart.  In each hole, there is a pin (for electrical signal) going through the hole, and a glass insulator material holding the pin centered through the length of the hole. In some of the products, we have electrical leakage occurring between the case and pin(s). When you measure this leakage with a Fluke 289 with the part on the table, it reads, say, 300 MΩ, drifting to say 350 MΩ, over the space of 1 minute. Not touching with your hands. However, when you touch the part with a finger, the ohm reading jumps down in the 100 MΩ range, and fluctuates. Generally it rises, but sometimes it goes down.

Is it maybe about the non-negligible DC resistance of the human and floor etc. in parallel with the high impedance? That or a small rectification effect from the large mains frequency currents through the human capacitor.

For high resistance, you may benefit from a controlled electric field environment - something akin to a Faraday cage...and/or you may need a test fixture whose leads to the meter can't move about. A rant: autoranging ohmmeters ought to be banned...I've too often had these go squirrelly, unable to settle on a desired range. Have you tried measuring conductance?

I don't have access to a schematic for that particular meter, but generally it's not a constant-current circuit but rather a resistance from some voltage source.
The ratio of the voltage across the unknown resistance and the voltage across a series reference resistor will give you the resistance (and the value of the voltage source cancels out). In many meters this is done by deriving a floating reference voltage for the ADC from the reference resistor.
Maybe there is a path that shunts the unknown resistance when you touch it, or maybe there's some effect from other voltages deliberately or accidentally there (eg. mains hum or some kind of RF). My rather old Fluke 8026B has 200nS range and I've not noticed any such misbehavior that could be blamed on the meter.
Human body capacitance is maybe 50 or 100pF and the time constant of 100pF * 500MΩ is 50ms- so in itself it's not going to have much of a perceptible effect on the readings.

Regarding your comment that the claim is that the current is constant, I still am not convinced. The '289 manual from here has the following entry:

You'll note that they specify the "typical short-circuit current" and "open circuit voltage" which is exactly what I would expect with the configuration described above- the current will be somewhat to greatly less when a resistance is inserted. Think of the Thevenin equivalent of a fixed voltage with a resistor in series.
In any case the time constant of that resistor and your resistance times human body capacitance is going to be short.
Equivalent circuit looks like this conceptually:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Short circuit current = 5V/Rreference
Open circuit voltage = 5V
Conductance measurement would be the reciprocal.

Fluke apparently behaves how I describe in my initial post. Per Fluke Tech support:
"When measuring resistance, a standard multimeter does not stick to a constant voltage across the load and measure current. It does the opposite: it sources a known current and measures the voltage across the load. The magnitude of the current depends on the range: the current is relatively small for high ranges and relatively large for low ranges."
They provided a chart showing constant current and measured voltage for different Ohm ranges (no way to add here). Ohm accuracy on a 289 is .05% of reading.

@ScottMiller - Hi, I'm one of the moderators here. I just happened to see your comment where you said there was "no way" to add a chart in a comment. Actually, although comments don't display images inline, you can add an image link in a comment with this technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) must not be submitted. The draft answer (or question) is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. || If that chart isn't yours, then details of its original source must be included e.g. name of source document etc.

Using SamGibson's suggestion, here is a link to the chart I mentioned.  It was sent by email from DeAndre Hampton, a Tech Support Engineer at Fluke, in response to the same question I initially asked.
https://i.sstatic.net/Knmw8ZaG.png
Spehro, interestingly I asked I follow-up question to Fluke, as BOTH the current and voltage have short/open/full scale values. Short and open circuit make sense, but if one or the other were fixed, I would expect "full scale" on the fixed parameter to be  "constant _______".
Also interesting how this chart ends at 40G when the 289 measures 500G

The chart ends at 40MΩ. The full scale voltage vs. open circuit voltage on the 40MΩ range  in that chart seems strange. The open-circuit voltage is what you'd expect with a resistor to a bandgap reference. It would be nice to confirm the claims with actual measurements. If you have a multimeter with a 10MΩ input resistance it can be used to measure low currents.

The capacitance of a human body should be negligible from the human body to other objects it's in the pF range.
What you are likely seeing is tiny currents generated from ESD voltages, the voltages are high and on humans and more particularly the clothes they wear can generate charging. So it's the charging that is probably changing and if either the currents or voltages change then you'll get a different reading for ohms. If you have any current generation in a device that is when the ohms reading can go negative (when it flips either V or I relative to what the meter is putting into the measured device).
